# When I create a directory in my res folder in android studio, it doesn't appear? even after refreshing

Tags: android, project, filenames

So in my project view I have only a drawable file. I'm following a book tutorial at the moment and it has drawable-ldpi etc. so to avoid confusion I thought I'd crate them too. The problem is that when I created my drawable-ldpi file, it simply didn't appear in my res folder, even after refreshing an restarting android studio.

I tried to create it again, and it says the directory already exists. What am I doing wrong here? why aren't the directories I've created appearing in my res folder?

[EDIT - Android project tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdzYI.png)

Comment: Post screenshot of your android studio folder tree

Comment: Just added a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

From the top left corner, just above App folder, where you see Android - with dropdown icon. Click on it and select project file from drop down options.

[image]

You can also select "Project"

[image]

Comment: I just did that and now my nothing but an app folder that can't be expanded is appearing. It looks like I've moved or deleted an import folder in the android studio directory.

Comment: I'm just going to do a fresh install and hopefully everything should work as intended then

Comment: check the physical location of your project folder. If you have contents then it should show under project file - as it is an explorer option for AStudio. so if you don't have a file it will not show. Otherwise, just try importing your project instead. It should work!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. It looks like I had deleted an important directory, a fresh install fixed everything. I think I may have dragged and dropped something accidentally. Thanks for the help!